# How I pass an object as a parameter in a ng-click within a ng-repeat? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How I pass an object as a parameter in a ng-click within a ng-repeat?

Example:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="table in tables">
    <td>{{ table.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ isActive(table.active) }}</td>
    <td>{{ table.initialDate }}</td>
    <td>{{ table.finalDate }}</td>
    <td>
        <button data-ng-click="updateTable(table)">Update</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> Inside the ng-click updateTable(**HERE**), I want to pass my object table.

Can someone help me?

Comment: last time I tried that it worked. what are you getting with `updateTable(table)`? You could use `$index` as `updateTable($index)` and inside your function `tables[$index] ` but as I said your first attempt seems fine from my end

Comment: Omg, I tested here and if I change my function for print table.name the function prints test. Forget it please, but thankyou for your attention!!!!!

Comment: You should post your find as your answer or close your question to remove it from the pool. Stack prefers if you post your own answer instead of closing it.

Answer (score 1):

In your component.html edit your code as shown below :

```
<td><button (click)=updateTable(table)>Update</button></td></tr>
```

then in your typescript code just declare the function

```
updateTable(table){
  console.log(table); //write your own code here!.
}
```