# Pass object in function with ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have template which starts like :

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="question in question.ChildQuestions" collapse-toggler ng-click="collapseQuestion(this);"> ...
```

In `collapseQuestion` i want to pass object that will be reffered to clicked `li`, but when i send it like `collapseQuestion(this);` i get some `Object` but it seems like it isn't `li` (i can't get any class of that object to check what exactly it is).

So what is correct way to pass object in `ng-click` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the event itself.

```
ng-click="collapseQuestion($event);"
```

Then in the function use `$event.currentTarget`

```
function collapseQuestion($event) {
    $event.currentTarget //do something with currentTarget
}
```

This post maybe of use: [get original element from ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23107613/1398425)

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-click="collapseQuestion(question)"
```

see 
[How I pass an object as a parameter in a ng-click within a ng-repeat? AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421761/how-i-pass-an-object-as-a-parameter-in-a-ng-click-within-a-ng-repeat-angularjs)